# Using Quaqua with a Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel, quaqua

I'm trying to use the Quaqua look and feel with a java project in netbeans, on windows 7.

So far, I've added quaqua.jar and swing-layout.jar to the libraries, and libquaqua.jnilib to the runtime "-Djava.library.path", but Netbeans simply tells me that "package ch.randelshofer.quaqua does not exist". This hasn't happened with any other LnF libraries I've used, but it does appear to be an issue with netbeans rather than the library files.

Anyone else had better luck using quaqua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by downloading the source and re-compiling a jar file. Not a great solution, especially since I don't know what will happen with the native libraries, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jnilib to `java.library.path`, or the directory in which the jnilib is located? The latter should be correct.

Comment: I actually tried both, at the moment I'm using the file itself.